# Copy part of a tables content and all records of other talbes referencing the copied records

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database

I want to create a procedure (or .Net code) that can easily copy several records of a table. Every table uses a surrogate key as primary key. Therefore I might not be able to simply copy the desired records using something like "INSERT INTO SELECT" because they might reference a wrong record

> Table 1 Customer: "ID", "Name", "Address", ...
>
> Table 2 Employee: "ID", "CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", ...
>
> Table 3 Project: "ID", "CustomerID", "Name", "ResponsibleEmployee", "StartDate", ...

Basically I want to be able to copy a complete customer (e.g. customer with ID 1 to a new customer with ID 2 that has already been created). That means that I need to copy every record of the other tables (in this example the tables "CustomerEmployee" and "Project"), set the field "CustomerID" to the new ID 2 and change the references (in this example the column "ResponsibleCustomerEmployee") to the one new record that has been copied as well.

My problem is that I have no idea what the best approach is to create something that can do exactly this. The best idea I came up with was to do a two step copy process. First copy all table content without touching the values of columns that reference other records. When inserting those records I would then write something like a mapping table that maps between old ID values and new ID values. In the second step I would then try to correct the references using the mapping table (meaning "copied Project with ID 1 referenced a CustomerEmployee with ID 2, according to the mapping table the ID of the copied CustomerEmployee is 20, therefore the copied Project must reference this new ID 20 instead of 2").

My question is if there is an easier way to achieve this goal? Or is my idea even working or am I missing something? I don't think that I'm the first person to encounter such a problem but I wasn't able to find a suitable solution out there on the internet. Maybe someone knows a solution or a even a third party .NET component that might do what I want (the database is used in a .NET application meaning that it must not necessarily be directly in SQL Server.

Update: Added example!

Before executing the copy process the tables should look like this (Note: ID is an identity column and everything that ends with ID references the corresponding table):

```
ID | Name         | Address
------------------------------------------
1  | "Customer 1" | "Street of Testcity 1"
2  | "Customer 2" | "Another Address"


ID | CustomerID | FirstName | LastName
--------------------------------------
1  | 1          | "John"    | "Doe"
2  | 1          | "Max"     | "Test"
3  | 2          | "Jane"    | "Doe"


ID | CustomerID | Name            | ResponsibleEmployeeID | StartDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | "Testproject 1" | 2                     | 2014-01-01
2  | 1          | "Testproject 2" | 1                     | 2014-01-01
```

Now I want to execute a copy process (stored procedure, .net Code or whatever does the trick) and copy the customer with the ID 1 and all related objects (i.e. all records that reference that customer using the defined foreign keys). The tables should look like this after the process has finished (the copied entries are marked with *):

```
ID | Name         | Address
------------------------------------------
1  | "Customer 1" | "Street of Testcity 1"
2  | "Customer 2" | "Another Address"
3  | "Customer 1" | "Street of Testcity 1"   *


ID | CustomerID | FirstName | LastName
--------------------------------------
1  | 1          | "John"    | "Doe"
2  | 1          | "Max"     | "Test"
3  | 2          | "Jane"    | "Doe"
4  | 3          | "John"    | "Doe"    *
5  | 3          | "Max"     | "Test"   *


ID | CustomerID | Name            | ResponsibleEmployeeID | StartDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | "Testproject 1" | 2                     | 2014-01-01
2  | 1          | "Testproject 2" | 1                     | 2014-01-01 
3  | 3          | "Testproject 1" | 5                     | 2014-01-01  *
4  | 3          | "Testproject 2" | 4                     | 2014-01-01  *
```

The problem I have is, that I need a way to fix the referenced records because what referenced CustomerID 1 should now reference CustomerID 3 (vice versa for employees)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to have a specific id to be assigned (only 20 should be assigned to record having id 2) you need to do so,other wise if you want the id an incremental of the max id in your table you can do it by a single query...

Comment: thanks for your comment but I don't really want specific IDs to be assigned. I just want the copied records to reference the other copied records and their new IDs (meaning that the IDs are generated when inserting the copied records). I added an example for better understanding what I want to achieve, maybe it will be clearer now but thanks anyway for trying!

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into Customer
select row_number() over(order by ID)+(select MAX(Id) from Customer) as id , 
Name,[Address] from Customer
```

This may help you......